# MySQL Explain gives different result for same query, query performance changes

Tags: mysql, performance

I've been having some performance issues on my production server. The main issue, I think is the table pricelist_entries, which has approximately 6 million rows. Basically its holds all of the products available. The query below usually takes a second to execute but ever since the table pricelist_entries grew past 3 million rows the execution time has started to increase. The weird thing is that sometimes the same query will take 10 seconds, other times 1 second. First I thought that maybe its the query cache but I disabled that and I still get the same variating result. What I can see from the two explains is that when its fast the query only accesses about 5000 rows while when its slow it seem to do an almost full table scan. I can't figure out why this happens. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure that *everything* is the same when MySQL produces those two different query execution plans? see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25276127/mysql-5-6-different-execution-plan-for-same-query-java-client-vs-terminal and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18218071/why-does-the-same-exact-query-produce-2-different-mysql-explain-results as those refer to a similar problem

Comment: Redguy - I can't really find anything different when i execute the query. I execute it on the same server.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for confirming that `innodb_buffer_pool_size` is OK.

Here are some ideas; I don't know which will be best:

**Plan A**

```
pricelist:  INDEX(pCurrent, tagged_to)
materials:  INDEX(companyID, article_nr_lev)
```

**Plan B**

```
SELECT STRAIGHT_JOIN ...
    FROM pricelist ...    -- first
    JOIN pricelist_entries ...
    LEFT JOIN materials
```

Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for each table; there could be some more clues there.

**More**

`materials.article_nr_lev = pricelist_entries.peArtnr` -- Whenever `JOINing`, the datatypes must be the same (or 'close').  Those two value are probably close enough -- same collation (mandatory) and both `VARCHAR`.  But they are of different lengths; I think that is 'close enough'.  However, do you sometimes need 255 characters, and sometimes need only 50?  For various subtle reasons (having to do with the execution of queries), it is better to keep `VARCHAR` sizes smaller (yet large enough to be safe).  I suspect the 255 could be changed to 50 without harm.

Also you have a lot of 4-byte `INT` fields that could probably be turned into smaller fields (eg, 2-byte `SMALLINT UNSIGNED`).  Shrinking table sizes often leads to improved performance, albeit minor.

`category int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT '0 - Inget val 1 - Alkov 2 - ...` -- Consider using `ENUM`.  That would avoid remembering the mapping.  (And take 1 byte instead of 4.)

Be careful about `CHARCTER SET` -- some columns are `dec8`, some are `utf8`.  The may be issues with comparisons, conversions, etc.  (I haven't noticed any problems with the query in question.)

Comment: Thank you for your post. I've posted the SHOW CREATE TABLE:s. I'll try out your suggestions =)

Comment: Added some minor notes.

Comment: Your post really helped. Not only did you provide solid solutions you also taught me something. Thank you Rick James =)